# Authenticating with Socialite on Laravel + JWT + Ember JS

Tags: laravel, ember.js, laravel-socialite, jwt

I have some issue authenticating with Socialite on Ember JS with Laravel.

I have an app where backend and frontend is separated. I am using JWT (tymondesings) as an authentication service. I am successfully redirecting to facebook, and receiving the response to my API and successfully registering the user on DB and getting the user via:

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)
```

The only problem I have is returning it in front end and authenticating so it can use the app. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you had a look at http://ember-simple-auth.com/?